# Sending Something to Serial and Writing it Returns a Correlated but Strange Number

Tags: serial, c++

I have an indescribable bug where read and write commands give back an array of numbers that are the digits of the input number except +48. Kinda hard to explain. Basically if I type 0 into this code:

```
    void setup(){
      Serial.begin(9600); //Begin serial connection
    }
    void loop(){
      if(Serial.available()){ //If serial available...
        double ser = Serial.read(); //Read serial value and write it to 'ser'
        Serial.println(ser); //Print 'ser'
      }
    }
```

I receive 48. 1 means 49, 2 means 50, 3 means 51... And then two digit numbers, which are the same except for each digit. 10 returns 49 48, 33 returns 51 51, 22 returns 50 50.

Answer (score 1):

Serial.read returns a character. The **character** '0' is 48 in decimal. So this is doing what you expect (or what I expect, anyway). I suggest not using `double` there, eg.

```
    char ser = Serial.read(); //Read serial value and write it to 'ser'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to output the value I get to a servo, which needs an int and it still separates the different characters into an array. Do you mind telling me a way to convert it into a full int?

Comment: `which needs an int and it still separates the different characters into an array` - I don't understand that. What array?

Comment: When transmitted textually, multi-digital value will indeed appear as something like a character array of the ASCII encoding of its digits.

Comment: Often we send 4 characters like "1234" over the serial link and want to store them in a single integer like "int position = 1234". One way to do it is to store the characters into a temporary buffer, and then [use "atoi()" or "atol()"](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14446/using-uart-to-set-rtc). Another way is [convert digits to an integer on the fly](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/sending-serial-data-to-arduino-from-matlabnot-using-support-package). Yet another way is to use [Serial.parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt).